# Can't open reference.aux

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

This is my first time posting here a question and I'm also like a beginner using Latex. Here is my problem:
I can't compile my references, and always give me this mistake:

I couldn't open file name `reference.aux'

Probably I have to install a extra .lib but I don't know which of them.

I'll appreciate a lot if someone could give me some advices...

Comment: Hi and welcome here! What exactly are you doing when you are "compiling your references"?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If your LaTeX document is called, say, `main.tex`, you have to call BibTeX (or Biber) like `bibtex main`, not with the name of the `.bib` file.

Answer (score 20):

Let's suppose your references are written in a file called 'ref.bib' with entries like:

```
@article{latex1977,
    title={How to use latex},
    author={John Smith},
    journal={Journal of Latex},
    pages={1--50},
    volume={39},
    year={1977}
}
```

Now in your main file say 'main.tex' you have to have something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin {document}

...
\cite{latex1977}
...

\bibliography{ref}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

To compile your document do this steps:

1. compile 'main.tex' using latex or pdflatex => this step will generate main.aux file
2. compile 'main.aux' (NOT 'ref.bib') using bibtex
3. compile twice 'main.tex' using latex or pdflatex

Comment: The compilation sequence you had written was not correct, so I changed it. You could also say that it is sufficient to use `bibtex main`, the `.aux` file ending is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for the help; I have a bash script for compiling my LaTeX files and was running `bibtex` on `bibfile.bib` instead of `bibfile`.